# File Handling and if else

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a program for my University project and I needed some help. 
I am trying to make a program which creates a file using ofstream and stores 1 or 0 in it (I've already found a way to store 0 or 1 in the file using random) and tells if the file contains 0 or 1 using if-else statements.

I'm having issue in reading the file, I can't find a way to make my program read that created file and tell whether it had 1 or 0 in it.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main () {
    int randu;
    srand((int) time(0));

    ofstream room;
    room.open("room0");
    room << rand() % 2;
    room.close();
    if (room.open("room0") == 1 ) {
        cout << "the room is occupied";
    }
    else {
        cout << "the room is free";
    }
    room.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check what `std::ifstream::open` returns. Certainly not the content of the file in a type that would even be comparable to an integer.

Comment: `open` would be a rather confusing name if it would `read`, no?

Comment: Don't reuse variables for multiple purposes. And don't try to read from an `ofstream`.

Comment: The thing I am wondering about is why there is no file extension on your file.

Comment: BTW, an `ofstream` is for **o**utput, `istream` for **i**nput.

Comment: @ArnavBorborah Files don't need extensions. It's common to have that as a hint for tools (Windows is especially fond of that), but beyond that they're really not necessary.

Comment: Yea, but my point was that a missing extension may have caused the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I'm having issue in reading the file*** ?
You are not reading anything in the code you shown.

Once the file is open and you want to check whether it's `0` or `1`, for that first you need to read from file and if you want to read something, then `room` should be object of `ifstream` class, not `ofstream` class.

You can use `getline()` or `get()` or `read()` for reading purpose.
For example: `char ch = room.get();`

Whether the file is open or not you can check using `fail()`:

```
if(room.fail()) {       
    cout << "the room is occupied";
}
else {
    cout << "the room is free";
}
```